# Error reading /odom topic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I write code to read the odometry data, I get errors while compiling.

> void test::odom_callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& odom_reading)

is the function i use. And I have also done in the constructor of the class:

> odom_listener = n.subscribe("odom", 10, test::odom_callback, this);

The dependency has been mentioned in manifest.xml. I have also included the nav_msgs/Odometry.h file

I get this error:
`In member function ‘void test::odom_callback(const ConstPtr&)’:`

`error: ‘const ConstPtr’ has no member named ‘twist’`

Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56448/error-reading-/odom-topic/) by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `odom_reading->twist` instead of `odom_reading.twist`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2013-02-27**:
SHIT! SUCH A BASIC C++ ERROR! THANKS A TON!

**Comment by [apletta](https://answers.ros.org/users/43189/apletta/) on 2019-07-03**:
This helped me so much!!